# Apple review guidelines inconvenience

Tags: ios

I have uploaded a build 4 months ago, and this is my fifth update. All builds approved seamlessly before, however surprisingly apple gave me today surprise reason of City and Profession(from signup form). Now as I don't have any choice, I made some major changes :(

My issue is, why this issue came suddenly, though apple takes such a long tenure of checking and validation(4 days in my case) also we are pledging good amount, unlike android which is far faster and convenient.

Or should I consider, apple indeed failed to work as per their own guidelines at initial level and troubling developers

@iOS developers please comment [image: Apple review for my app]

Comment: Honestly, best way would be to deal with this as more you'll post or reply, more time it would take for the app to be approved. Now having said that, you can always post on forum or tag apple (not here). I am not very sure if bug reporter is the right way to post your grievance. I would like to hear what others have In mind.

Comment: Pretty straightforward... From Review Guidelines: `Apps may not require users to enter personal information to function, except when directly relevant to the core functionality of the app or required by law.` Your explanation in your screen cap pretty much says "We want to violate that Guideline"

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: sorry but i dont have 1500 reputation score to mark apple as yet:(. However I wanted all developers to know such issues. and dont waste time with arguing apple review team, like I did!

Answer (score 0):

It is a common occurrence for Apple to miss something that violates the guidelines initially and reject an app later because of it. I've personally seen a reputable app get rejected for the app icon even though that icon had been in use for months prior to the rejection.

You have to realize that app reviews are done by **humans** and not nearly as automated as the play store review process. Humans are prone to error and bias. You may have one reviewer that says an aspect of your app follows the guidelines, while another disagrees. You may have a reviewer that doesn't notice an issue at first, but does months later.

The review process can be annoying and inconsistent but it does help Apple to enforce some level of quality in the App Store.